# Setting JS variable to $.get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying multiple methods to get the returned data from a $.get method but am having no luck. So far, the code below returns an alert with the data I want but what I want to achieve is setting the **finalPublicIp** variable to the returned data so that I may use this variable in other places.

```
var finalPublicIp = $.get("https://api.ipify.org/", function(data){
    alert("Data: " + data);
});
```

Thank you for all help in advance.

Comment: Can you include the code which you wrote to call the method??

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the `$.get()` method is asynchronous. You have to assign  the value in the callback method:

```
var finalPublicIp;

$.get("https://api.ipify.org/", function(data){
    finalPublicIp = data;
});
```

Note that due to the asynchronous behavior, the value of `finalPublicIp` will only be set after the callback method is executed.

Comment: When alerting the var now, it returns undefined?

Comment: @mrchriswindsor Because the asynchronous callback has not finished executing yet. You have to wrap your head around this asynchronous behavior first.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen oh my bad. I understand what you are saying now. So there is no way to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah, you could get your AJAX method to executed synchronously, but this is not the preferred approach as it blocks the entire processing loop. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have reviewed that answer and have tried a few things. Could you be ever so kind sir and show me how I would change my method to be non-synchronous. Any more help is extremely appreciated!